# How to Disable React Minified Error Messages?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, devtools

I'm currently trying to figure out where an error is manifesting in my app, and am wondering how to change the minified chunks to function names with line numbers for local development.

Here are the messages I'm getting:

[image]

In my `server.js` file, I added the following code to try to resolve this:

```
if(IS_LOCAL) {
    process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm assuming you're using webpack here, what does your webpack.config file look like, please?

Comment: @BrettEast, I'm not using webpack, although there are some libraries that have webpack as a dependency.

Comment: Okay, are you using create-react-app?

Comment: @BrettEast - I am! I learned that I had to pass a proxy to my package.json file to use development mode! Thank you so much for checking!